# When is the Laplace transform of a function continuous?

Tags: analysis, continuity, laplace-transform

Are there any general conditions on a function so that its Laplace transform is continuous? e.g. what conditions on $f:\mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ guarantee that its Laplace transform 
$$F\left(s\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(t\right)e^{-st}dt$$
is continuous? It seems to me that if $f$ has compact support and is bounded, then it ought to be. The idea I have is that we get 
$$\left|F\left(s'\right)-F\left(s\right)\right|\leq\int_{0}^{y}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|\left|e^{-st}\right|dt$$
by making $s'$ and $s$ close enough, it seems we can make the RHS arbitrarily small. I haven't been able to complete a proof. Additionally, can we change the assumptions? Are there more natural assumptions to get continuity?

Comment: You shouldn't really need absolute alues around  $e^{-st}$ Laplace transform is real valued ;)

Comment: @N8tron Laplace transform real-valued?  How on earth?

Comment: Okay yeah. That comment is wrong. Apparently we only teach the real valued one in the class I've taught :)

Comment: Deduce conditions with dominated convergence in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want it continuous on all of $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$), the necessary and sufficient condition is that $f$ is measurable and $f(t) e^{-st}$ is integrable for all $s \in \mathbb R$.  Then the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem gives you the desired continuity.

EDIT: More explicitly, suppose $f$ satisfies the above condition, and take any $s \in \mathbb C$.  For $|s' - s| \le 1$ and $t \ge 0$, 
$$\left|f(t) e^{-st} - f(t) e^{-s' t}\right| \le 2 \left|f(t) e^{(1+|s|)t}\right|$$
the right side being integrable on $[0,\infty)$ by assumption.
As $s \to s'$, $f(t) e^{-s't} - f(t) e^{-st} \to 0$ for all $t$, and the 
Dominated Convergence Theorem says $$\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-s' t} \; dt \to \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st}\; dt $$

Comment: I'm not looking for continuity on all of $\mathbb {R}$ or $\mathbb {C}$. Nonetheless, a welcome insight :)

Comment: @JoshuaTilley: If $f$  is bounded and has compact support then the above gives your desired result.

Comment: Can someone be a bit more explicit?

Comment: Could a similar result be stated in terms of the improper Riemann integral?

Comment: I don't know of good limit theorems for improper Riemann integrals that converge, but not absolutely.  If $\int_0^\infty |f(t) e^{-st}|\; dt$ converges as an improper Riemann integral, then the Lebesgue theorem covers it.